# Safely limit number of SSH connections per user

Tags: ubuntu

How do I safely limit the max number of SSH connections that can be started by a user group?
I added the user group in `limits.conf` with this line

```
@usergroup - maxlogins 2
```

This works in most usecases, but it doesn't work when users start a tmux/screen session.
They can create many tmux windows (which is desirable), but when they close the terminal window without closing the tmux windows, they cannot login to the server again because their tmux windows each count as a SSH connection.

This effectively locks them out. How do I prevent that?